# Expandable listview child default selection always position 0, when group expand

Tags: android

I have develop ExpandableListView perfectly.When user click the group row, the children list is expanded and show perfectly ,My question is how to show child index 0 always checked when group expand,Please help me ..

parent.setItemChecked(index, true);

working fine when click child, but cant set default selection position as 0 for every child group

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you try listening to [OnGroupExpandListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener.html) then use [setSelectedChild](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html#setSelectedChild%28int,%20int,%20boolean%29)?

Comment: Thanks ..ya tried this,but i want to highlight different background color for  0 th position child when group expand

Comment: @user1507832, then why don't you set a fix background for child in position 0th? because the child view only visible when group expanded.

Comment: now background changed succesfully with use of itemselector drawable in setOnChildClickListener,here need one thing how to trigger itemselector  background of 0 th child position automatically when group expand

Answer (score 1):

After using **OnGroupExpandListener**  , You can check which group is  `expand`

```
 YOUR_EXP_LISTVIEW.setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                            int groupPosition, long id) {

                    if(parent.isGroupExpanded(groupPosition))
                    {

                     // Do your Staff
                    }
                    else{

                       // Expanded ,Do your Staff

                    }


                    return false;
                }
            });
```

Or try this way..

```
    setOnGroupExpandListener(new OnGroupExpandListener() {

    @Override
     public void onGroupExpand(int arg0) {

     // Your staff
      }
       });
```

Comment: thanks Amiya, i need something like setItemChecked(grouposition,0, true) for default 0 th position checked when open group

Comment: ya i tried 2nd one ,still cant change background of 0 th child position